# How to insert the diagonal symbol of a matrix in latex

Tags: matrices

It is common in literature to encounter the diagonal symbol when referring to matrices. For instance, if matrix A is diagonal, it can be denoted as [\A] where the "\" symbol is crossing the letter "A" from the upper left to the lower right corner.

Is there any way to do this in LaTeX (maybe by the use of any particular package)?

An example of what I am intending to do can be seen on the picture below.

[image]

Comment: eeuw those are big backslashes. if a matrix is diagonal write diag. and no this is not common in matrix algebra field. Maybe at other fields actually i never saw these before.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one option using the [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) library to define a command (using the optional argument one can control the vertical size):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcounter{mydiagm}

\newcommand\DiagMat[2][1]{
\stepcounter{mydiagm}
\begin{bmatrix}
\tikzmark{start-\themydiagm}\rule{1cm}{0pt}\\[#1\normalbaselineskip]\hfill\tikzmark{end-\themydiagm}
\end{bmatrix}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
\draw ([yshift=1ex]pic cs:start-\themydiagm) -- node[fill=white,inner sep=2pt] {$#2$} (pic cs:end-\themydiagm);%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\DiagMat{c^{2}}\frac{\partial C_{l}}{\partial C_{T}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\DiagMat[2]{ce}
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\ b \\ c \\ d
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The code needs two or three runs for the rule to reach its final position.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mydiag}[1]{\left[%
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}}
\diagdown &    & \\
          & #1 & \\
          &    & \diagdown
\end{array}\right]
}
\begin{equation}
\mydiag{ce}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\mydiag{c^2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

There is a `\diagdown` symbol from `amssymb` which you can use in this case.